# Unexpected behaviour of font-size of paragraphs inside a flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, font-size

There is some unexpected behaviour of paragraphs inside a flexbox. This only happens on chrome mobile when checking 'request desktop site' or when you are in the developer tools in chrome and turn on 'device toolbar' and set the device size to something small (like 320x500).
For an example, see the following html:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=980">
  <style>
    p {
      border: solid red 1px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>These should be the same size</p>

  <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;">
    <p>These should be the same size</p>
    <div style="width: 830px;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et dolor purus. Etiam ut hendrerit erat. Fusce finibus faucibus velit ac fringilla. Praesent sollicitudin arcu non eleifend rutrum. Mauris convallis sagittis ornare.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Expected behaviour: all the font sizes should be the same. This is clearly not the case, see screenshot.

[image: Incorrect font-size]

However, when removing one line from the 'Lorem ipsum' paragraph everthing becomes the same small size (which is also what I expected in the previous example).

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et dolor purus. Etiam ut hendrerit erat. Fusce finibus faucibus velit ac fringilla. Praesent sollicitudin arcu non eleifend rutrum.</p>
```

[image: Correct behaviour]

Is there something wrong in this code, is this a browser bug or maybe something in the html/css specification? I only tested this in chrome on android and chrome on windows 10.

Comment: Well, the content in the meta is not correct. This is not CSS. It should be `content="width=980"` (without `px` or `;` and with `=` instead of `:`).

Comment: Do have a css document that you're using?

Comment: @MrLister This does not matter it has the same effect. Also removing the meta completely does not change the behaviour. Setting it to `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` does make it correct on chrome desktop, but not on mobile.

Comment: @Matt-the-Marxist All the styles are inline in the html document, so I don't have an css document. (Did this on purpose to reduce the code size).

Comment: @wuppie367 did that edit help?

Comment: @godfather I set it to `font-size: 2vw;`, but this still has the same behaviour.

Comment: yeah i saw the problem now i can see what you want

Comment: add flex-direction:column; remove flex-wrap; and justify:content;

Comment: @godfather Still the same behaviour: https://imgur.com/a/we1YmjM

Comment: if you remove  styled flex it works?

Comment: @godfather Yes, changing `display: flex` to `display: block` results in the same text sizes. Though this is not really a solution. Although what is odd, when changing it to a block, it affects the font-size in the first `p` that was not in the flex-box (it scaled up to match the other font-sizes).

Comment: ill test it in my vscode  on chromium

Comment: can you try to add this text-size-adjust: 100%; in the p

Comment: @godfather Ah yes, that fixes it. Setting it to either none or 100% results in the same font sizes. Thank you very much. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: ive added the answer ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use text-size-adjust

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=980">
  <style>
    p {
      border: solid red 1px;
      font-size: 16px;
       text-size-adjust:100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p>These should be the same size</p>

  <div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;">
    <p>These should be the same size</p>
    <div style="width: 830px;">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et dolor purus. Etiam ut hendrerit erat. Fusce finibus faucibus velit ac fringilla. Praesent sollicitudin arcu non eleifend rutrum. Mauris convallis sagittis ornare.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```